# SSIS Precedence constraints flow based on variable value

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have SSIS with the logic SQL check if the record for the file exists in the FileList table, then it is executed. There is INT32 count variable in the package.

Execute SQL task contains
SQL statement: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM dbo.FileList WHERE [file] LIKE '%File1%'`

Parameter Mapping: User::count Output direction, BYTE data type, 0 param name and -1 param size.

Result Set: count, User::count

SQL check task is connected with subsequent data flow task if the file exists or next SQL check (see screenshot).

Precedence Constraint has Value: Success Expression: `@[User::count]>0`

Another Precedence Constraint has Value: Success Expression: `@[User::count]==0`

I want to trigger the validation as there is no File1 to import and there is no %File1% records in the table.

Currently when executed, I see the green tick on Execute SQL task and the execution stops successfully while I expect it to run on one branch or another.

[image: Finished Successfully]

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I implement the custom flow to run the packages based on the check of availability in the table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the two precedent constraints leading to `SQL check File2`.

The default behavior is for the two constraints to be bound by a logical `AND`, which is to say they *both* need to be `TRUE` in order for the next task to start. Given your flow, though, you want a logical `OR`, meaning the task will start if *either* constraint returns a `TRUE`.

Right click on either constraint and change the default at the bottom of the dialogue box:

[image: Screenshot of part of the precedent constraint configurations]

As shown, this is what you'll find. Once you change the selection to Logical OR, the constraints will turn into dotted lines instead of the solid lines that are there now.

*Edit (based on the question in the comments):*

> [O]nce I add File1 to the folder and File1 record in the database, I still see Load File1 task never starting. It is always going to SQL Check File2 branch. The underlying query returns the value of 1. Is there something wrong with variable setup?

When I need to pass a count to a variable, rather than using an output parameter, I use `Result Set`. On the `General` tab of the `Execute SQL Task`, set `Result Set` to `Single Row`. On the `Result Set` tab of the editor, set `Result Name` to `0`, and select the variable you want the results mapped to from the `Variable Name` list.

That should insure that the `@count` variable is getting the `1` from the query and ought to correct the flow to call `Load File1`.

Comment: Thank you Eric. 
I altered both lines setting Logical OR and SQL Check File2 task started. However, once I add File1 to the folder and File1 record in the database, I still see Load File1 task never starting. It is always going to SQL Check File2 branch. The underlying query returns the value of 1. Is there something wrong with variable setup?

Comment: @RandyMcKay, I edited the answer with a possible solution. You may want to put an after execution breakpoint on the SQL task and verify the values of the variables in the Locals window to be sure the value assignments are working as expected.

Comment: Glad it helped!